# Kernel dies while executing papermill

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, papermill

I am trying to automatically generate several notebooks with papermill using the following code:

```py
template = "preprocessing_template.ipynb"
parameters = {"allowed_values":[0,1], "epsilon":0.01, "to_csv":True}
kernel_name = "my_env"
grid_folders_csv_names_outputs = [("dir_a", "a.csv","output_a.ipynb"),\
                                  ("dir_b", "b.csv","output_b.ipynb"),\
                                  ("dir_c", "c.csv","output_c.ipynb"),
                                 [

def execute_notebook(template,output_file,parameters,kernel_name,grid_folder,csv_name):

    parameters["grid_folder"]=grid_folder
    parameters["csv_name"]=csv_name
    nb = pm.execute_notebook(template,
                        output_file,
                        parameters=parameters,
                        kernel_name=kernel_name)
    #nbs = []
    #nbs.append(nb)
    return nb

for grid_folder, csv_name, output_file in tqdm(grid_folders_csv_names_outputs):
    execute_notebook(template,output_file,parameters,kernel_name,grid_folder,csv_name)
```

Nevertheless, I get an error message

```
DeadKernelError: Kernel died
```

which seems to happen because the memory is completely flooded as I have checked by monitoring the system while running the code. Apparently the code snippet above generates several processes to run the parameterized notebooks, and these processes are not killed once an iteration is complete, thus accumulating in memory. What could I do to solve this issue? I am using Ubuntu 18.04 and the code is run in an anaconda 2019.10 environment.

Comment: If you run papermill from CLI, can you enable logging to see where execution is failing?